# Remote selenium on Docker does not handle Javascript correctly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, selenium, docker, capybara

I have a Rails app using a remote Selenium server to run its Capybara tests.

Both the Rails app and the Selenium server are Dockerized and connected successfully: https://github.com/mottalrd/capybara-on-dockerized-selenium/blob/master/docker-compose.yml

My problem is that executing Javascript on the remote Selenium server on Docker does not work. For example this line works perfectly if I run my browser test locally:

`page.execute_script("$('#js-fileupload').fileupload('send', {files: $('#input_file')[0].files});")`

But fails on the remote Selenium as follows. What could be the issue?

```
 Failure/Error: page.execute_script("$('#js-fileupload').fileupload('send', {files: $('#input_file')[0].files});")

 Selenium::WebDriver::Error::UnknownError:
    (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
   Command duration or timeout: 12 milliseconds
   Build info: version: '2.53.0', revision: '35ae25b', time: '2016-03-15 17:00:58'
   System info: host: 'b5f51c04b891', ip: '172.18.0.2', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '4.1.19-boot2docker', java.version: '1.8.0_03-Ubuntu'
   Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver
   Capabilities [{applicationCacheEnabled=true, rotatable=false, handlesAlerts=true, databaseEnabled=true, version=45.0.2, platform=LINUX, nativeEvents=false, acceptSslCerts=true, webStorageEnabled=true, locationContextEnabled=true, browserName=firefox, takesScreenshot=true, javascriptEnabled=true, cssSelectorsEnabled=true}]
   Session ID: 40cdda26-bc78-4d56-b3d7-1025483a985b (org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException)
 # [remote server] sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java):-2:in `newInstance0'
 # [remote server] sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java):62:in `newInstance'
 # [remote server] sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java):45:in `newInstance'
 # [remote server] java.lang.reflect.Constructor(Constructor.java):423:in `newInstance'
 # [remote server] org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler(ErrorHandler.java):206:in `createThrowable'
 # [remote server] org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler(ErrorHandler.java):158:in `throwIfResponseFailed'
 # [remote server] org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver(RemoteWebDriver.java):678:in `execute'
 # [remote server] org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver(RemoteWebDriver.java):577:in `executeScript'
 # [remote server] sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor20():-1:in `invoke'
 # [remote server] sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java):43:in `invoke'
 # [remote server] java.lang.reflect.Method(Method.java):498:in `invoke'
 # [remote server] org.openqa.selenium.support.events.EventFiringWebDriver$2(EventFiringWebDriver.java):103:in `invoke'
 # [remote server] com.sun.proxy.$Proxy1():-1:in `executeScript'
 # [remote server] org.openqa.selenium.support.events.EventFiringWebDriver(EventFiringWebDriver.java):217:in `executeScript'
 # [remote server] org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.handler.ExecuteScript(ExecuteScript.java):56:in `call'
 # [remote server] java.util.concurrent.FutureTask(FutureTask.java):266:in `run'
 # [remote server] org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultSession$1(DefaultSession.java):176:in `run'
 # [remote server] java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor(ThreadPoolExecutor.java):1142:in `runWorker'
 # [remote server] java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java):617:in `run'
 # [remote server] java.lang.Thread(Thread.java):745:in `run'
 # /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.53.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/response.rb:70:in `assert_ok'
 # /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.53.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/response.rb:34:in `initialize'
 # /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.53.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/common.rb:78:in `new'
 # /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.53.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/common.rb:78:in `create_response'
 # /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.53.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/default.rb:90:in `request'
 # /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.53.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/common.rb:59:in `call'
 # /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.53.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/bridge.rb:649:in `raw_execute'
 # /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.53.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/bridge.rb:627:in `execute'
 # /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.53.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/bridge.rb:353:in `executeScript'
 # /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.53.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/driver.rb:220:in `execute_script'
 # /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/capybara-2.7.0/lib/capybara/selenium/driver.rb:81:in `execute_script'
 # /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/capybara-2.7.0/lib/capybara/session.rb:524:in `execute_script'
 # ./spec/features/happy_path_spec.rb:95:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
 # /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/vcr-3.0.1/lib/vcr/util/variable_args_block_caller.rb:9:in `call_block'
 # /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/vcr-3.0.1/lib/vcr.rb:189:in `use_cassette'
 # ./spec/features/happy_path_spec.rb:10:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Comment: It is worth adding that I am using the jquery file upload library and all the javascript seems to be running fine, apart the pieces that interact with that. Could it be some JS load issue?

Comment: When it comes to file uploads in a remote environment, I think you would need to make use of something like the LocalFileDetector (https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/java/client/src/org/openqa/selenium/remote/LocalFileDetector.java) for uploads to work properly in the remote environment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the following code

```
page.execute_script("$('#js-fileupload').fileupload('send', {files: $('#input_file')[0].files});")
```

What you are effectively saying is that the path you specified in `input_file` text box should be uploaded. When you run it locally the path is accessible to the browser and can be uploaded. By in a containerized app/browser the path inside containers have nothing to do with path on the host

So you need to make sure that your browser container has a volume mapped using `-v /path/on/host:/path/on/container` and then you need to update your scripts to make sure that you use `/path/on/container` for the upload field

Comment: Automated tests usually use files located within the project folder, so you might want to map it into container running browser, so that path to the file will be the same.
```
services:
  app:
    volumes:
       - .:/app
  selenium:
    volumes:
      - .:/app
```